# Transfering files from Mac to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mac, file-sharing, grsync

I'm a newbie, so please forgive my ignorance. I'm trying to find out how to transfer files from an iMac to Ubuntu 18.04. What is the best and easiest method and how do I go about performing it (step by step instructions)? I use Grsync for backing up Ubuntu.

Comment: Which version of MacOS?

Answer (score 0):

A. Copy the files up to iCloud or another cloud service, then access them from the Ubuntu PC: No easier way.

B. Create an [exFAT](https://www.howtogeek.com/235596/whats-the-difference-between-fat32-exfat-and-ntfs/) partition on an external USB flashdrive, SSD, or HDD with the MacOS [Disk Utility](https://www.howtogeek.com/255251/how-to-erase-and-format-a-usb-drive-on-your-mac/). Copy the files you wish to migrate onto the exFAT partition. Unmount the exFAT drive, attach it to the Ubuntu machine, [mount it](https://itsfoss.com/mount-exfat/), and copy the files onto your /home or data partition.

Comment: To copy files on to the flash drive and then, once mounted in Ubuntu, I can just click and drag them, can't I?

Comment: Yes, and exFAT makes that easy.